# Encoding unique features

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have an excel sheet with 2 columns:

1. Words 2. Language

There is only one word on each row and it is directly linked to a language

How would I format those words and languages into machine learning acceptable data?

I'm using scikit-learn and thought about bag of words but it seemed to me that indexation of every word wouldn't convey the characteristics of each word.

Comment: What is your classification task? What do you want to be the input and output of the trained system?

Comment: @Hossein The task would be to classify a given word as either english or dutch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question, I think you are asking about how to extract features from words to be used to train a classifier for determining the language of the words. I think the *length of the word* and the *character bigrams in the word* are good features to start with. Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18658106/quick-implementation-of-character-n-grams-using-python) for extracting character bigrams. In addition, maybe it is suitable to use the NLTK classifiers. For example,

```
from nltk.classify import NaiveBayesClassifier
nb = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set)
```

where `train_set` should be a list of tuples of the form `[(features, label)]`, where `features` is a `dict` of the form `{feature_name: feature_value}`.

Comment: This works, Thanks!
Do you also know how to implement this in scikit-learn?
Or should these types of classification problems only be done by nltk?

Comment: @JesseVermeulen You can also use scikit-learn. Look at [this link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB).

Comment: Thanks fo the help!