# Inbuilt Python Function for String Comparison like N-gram

Tags: python

Is there is any inbuilt function in Python Which performs like `Ngram.Compare('text','text2')` String Comparison.I don't want to install N-gram module.I tried all the Public and Private Functions which i got by doing `dir('text')`

I want to get a percentage Match on comparison of two strings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fast n-gram calculation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591258/fast-n-gram-calculation)

Comment: @thewolf Sorry for the confusion i don't want Ngrams. I need the percentage match of the two strings

Comment: What do you mean by 'percentage' match? Could you provide some sample input/output?

Comment: NGram.compare('spa', 'spam') gives result 0.375 ie 37.5%

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[difflib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) in the standard library.

You can also do a Levenshtein distance:

```
def lev(seq1, seq2):
    oneago = None
    thisrow = range(1, len(seq2) + 1) + [0]
    for x in xrange(len(seq1)):
        twoago, oneago, thisrow = oneago, thisrow, [0] * len(seq2) + [x + 1]
        for y in xrange(len(seq2)):
            delcost = oneago[y] + 1
            addcost = thisrow[y - 1] + 1
            subcost = oneago[y - 1] + (seq1[x] != seq2[y])
            thisrow[y] = min(delcost, addcost, subcost)
    return thisrow[len(seq2) - 1]

def di(seq1,seq2):
    return float(lev(seq1,seq2))/min(len(seq1),len(seq2))

print lev('spa','spam')
print di('spa','spam')
```

Answer (score 6):

You want the Levenshtein distance which is implemented through

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-Levenshtein/

Not wanting to install something means: you have to write the code yourself.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance