# Tokenize with ngram range

Tags: python, string, split, nltk, tokenize

There is any way to tokenize strings with ngram range? Like when u get the features from a CountVectorizer. For example, (w ngram range = (1,2)):

```
strings = ['this is the first sentence','this is the second sentence']
```

to

```
[['this','this is','is','is the','the','the first',''first','first sentence','sentence'],['this','this is','is','is the','the','the second',''second','second sentence','sentence']]
```

Update: iterating over n i get:

```
sentence = 'this is the first sentence'

nrange_array = []
    for n in range(1,3):
        nrange = ngrams(sentence.split(),n)
        nrange_array.append(nrange)

for nrange in nrange_array:
    for grams in nrange:
        print(grams)
```

output:

```
('this',)
('is',)
('the',)
('first',)
('sentence',)
('this', 'is')
('is', 'the')
('the', 'first')
('first', 'sentence')
```

and i want:

```
('this','this is','is','is the','the','the first','first','first sentence','sentence')
```

Comment: @SebaCarnena: what have you tried?

Comment: I've the tokenized data with 1(sgram) and 2 (bigrams) ngrams (at the level of word). Then, I tried to append them, and get an array with sgrams under the bigrams. 
So i tried .concat with pandas too, and get the same but in different axis.
Now im trying to do a for loop but I think that can exists a better way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [n-grams in python, four, five, six grams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17531684/n-grams-in-python-four-five-six-grams)

Comment: No. That topic is about getting tokens of ngrams, and I want to get tokens in a range of ngrams, isnt the same.

Comment: @SebaChamena: there is not much difference, just iterate over the `n`...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i updated the question right now, explaining why that doesnt worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope that code could help you.

```
x = "this is the first sentence"
words = x.split()
result = []

for index, word in enumerate(words):
      result.append(word)

  if index is not len(words) - 1:
        result.append(" ".join([word, words[index + 1]]))

print(result) # Output: ["this", "this is", ...]
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks u.

Comment: @SebaChamena No problem!