# mongodb find a pattern of an input

Tags: regex, mongodb, pymongo

I need to find all the results that start with certain input for example for the inputs: "Paul", "pau", "paul Gr", "Paul Green", "Paul Gree" , "Pel", "pele", "joh","john" etc.. The search has to be case insensive..
it suppose to return all of these(the input search string is at least 3 characters long):

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5e6ffe413f71835ae3aa4b60"),
    "f": "Paul",
    "id": 11811,
    "l": "Pelè",
    "r": 64
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5e6ffe413f71835ae3aa4b65"),
    "f": "paul",
    "id": 11811,
    "l": "walker",
    "r": 64
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5e6ffe413f71835ae3aa4b66"),
    "f": "johnny",
    "id": 11811,
    "l": "Green",
    "r": 64
  }
]
```

tried to do the following:

```
 contain_searched_term_players = list(db.players_collection.find({'$or': [{'f': {'$regex': searched_player_name_string, '$options': 'i'}},
                                                                         {'l': {'$regex': searched_player_name_string, '$options': 'i'}},
                                                                         {'c': {'$regex': searched_player_name_string, '$options': 'i'}}]}).sort([{'r', -1}])
```

but it doesnt work for "Paul Green"

**searched_player_name_string is the given input(the inputs above, for example Paul Green)**

Comment: What does `searched_player_name_string` look like?

Comment: it is the given input, for example "Paul Green"

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide correct Regex for query condition

```
^(Paul Green|Paul Gree|Paul|paul|pau|Gr|pele|Pel|john|joh)
```

[RegexPlayground](https://regex101.com/r/7xRhAk/1)

```
searched_player_name_string = "^(Paul Green|Paul Gree|Paul|paul|pau|Gr|pele|Pel|john|joh)"
result_cursor = db.players_collection.find({
  "$or": [
    {
      "f": {
        "$regex": searched_player_name_string,
        "$options": "i"
      }
    },
    {
      "l": {
        "$regex": searched_player_name_string,
        "$options": "i"
      }
    },
    {
      "c": {
        "$regex": searched_player_name_string,
        "$options": "i"
      }
    }
  ]
})
searched_player_name_string = list(result_cursor)
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/F51GFFj9sLC)

Comment: You need split your input into parts and create Regex

Comment: how can I do that ?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17531684/n-grams-in-python-four-five-six-grams)

Answer (score 0):

Split your input in separate strings, run the query on each and append the results together (checking first it's not already found), Finally sort the results:

```
searched_player_name_string = 'Paul Green'
found_players = []

for regex in searched_player_name_string.split():
    contain_searched_term_players = db.players_collection.find({'$or': [{'f': {'$regex': regex, '$options': 'i'}},
                                                                             {'l': {'$regex': regex, '$options': 'i'}},
                                                                             {'c': {'$regex': regex, '$options': 'i'}}]})
    for player in contain_searched_term_players:
        # The next line avoids creating duplicate answers if there are multiple matches for the same player
        if player['_id'] not in [ o['_id'] for o in found_players ]:
            found_players.append(player)

# Sort the output by "r" - highest first
pprint.pprint(sorted(found_players, key=lambda o: o['r'], reverse=True))
```

Comment: my goal is to implement search like that 
https://www.futbin.com/