# Implement search subtext mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have an object like this

```
{
   "_id":2939399,
   "name:"Lionel Messi"
}
```

want the searches: Lio, nel, ssi, Lionel, Mess, Lione, Messi, etc ... (All substrings that are more than 3 characters long) will yield me this result(Lionel Messi object)- how that can be achieved?

I have tried to put an index on the name field bit this works partially and gives me results only when I search Messi or Lionel..

Comment: Have you considered using regex for the partial search?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking if a field contains a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610131/checking-if-a-field-contains-a-string)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongodb find a pattern of an input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60787323/mongodb-find-a-pattern-of-an-input)

Comment: This is my post , so NO

Comment: _"I have tried to put an index on the name field bit this works partially and gives me results only when I search Messi or Lionel."_: That is you have tried a  [text search](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/index.html). Searching a part of the string of "Lionel" or "Messi" requires using a [regex search](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/index.html).  Regex searches may or may not use indexes effectively.