# How can I look for specific bigrams in text example - python?

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, nltk

I am interested in finding how often (in percentage) a set of words, as in n_grams appears in a sentence.

```
example_txt= ["order intake is strong for Q4"]

def find_ngrams(text):
    text = re.findall('[A-z]+', text)
    content = [w for w in text if w.lower() in n_grams] # you can calculate %stopwords using "in"
    return round(float(len(content)) / float(len(text)), 5)

#the goal is for the above procedure to work on a pandas datafame, but for now lets use 'text' as an example.
#full_MD['n_grams'] = [find_ngrams(x) for x in list(full_MD.loc[:,'text_no_stopwords'])]
```

Below you see two examples. The first one works, the last doesn't.

```
n_grams= ['order']
res = [find_ngrams(x) for x in list(example_txt)]
print(res)
Output:
[0.16667]

n_grams= ['order intake']
res = [find_ngrams(x) for x in list(example_txt)]
print(res)
Output:
[0.0]
```

How can I make the find_ngrams() function process bigrams, so the last example from above works?

Edit: Any other ideas?

Comment: what is n_grams ???

Comment: that is the word/words i am interested in finding the precentage for how often it is mentioned in example_txt.

Comment: Apologizes, I added some exaplanation in question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [SpaCy Matcher](https://spacy.io/api/matcher):

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
# Add match ID "orderintake" with no callback and one pattern
pattern = [{"LOWER": "order"}, {"LOWER": "intake"}]
matcher.add("orderintake", None, pattern)

doc = nlp("order intake is strong for Q4")
matches = matcher(doc)
print(len(matches)) #Number of times the bi-gram appears in text
```

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
re.findall('[A-z]+', text)
```

returns

```
['order', 'intake', 'is', 'strong', 'for', 'Q'].
```

For this reason, the string 'order intake' will not be matched in your for here:

```
content = [w for w in text if w.lower() in n_grams]
```

If you want it to match, you'll need to make one single of string from each Bigram.

Instead, you should probably use [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_text_processing/python_bigrams.htm) to find Bigrams.

For N-grams, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17547860/3335606) answer.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have already exploited this option, but why not use the a simple .count combined with len:

```
(example_txt[0].count(n_grams[0]) * len(n_grams[0])) / len(example_txt[0])
```

or if you are not interested in the spaces as part of your calculation you can use the following:

```
(example_txt[0].count(n_grams[0])* len(n_grams[0])) / len(example_txt[0].replace(' ',''))
```

of course you can use them in a list comprehension, this was just for demonstration purposes

---

Comment: Interesting approach. I guess what it has to be modified to look for whole sentences as it right now looks at characters.

Comment: right now it's finding substrings within a given string. The [0] are only there because the sentence and string examples you took are placed in a list

Comment: I understand. The result of your example code is 50%, which only makes sense if we count characters. How can we make it look for words?