# Token pattern for n-gram in TfidfVectorizer in python

Tags: python, regex, scikit-learn, n-gram

Does TfidfVectorizer identify n-grams using python [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)?

This issue arises while reading the documentation for [scikit-learn TfidfVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html), I see that the pattern to recognize n-grams at the word level is `token_pattern=u'(?u)\b\w\w+\b'`. I am having trouble seeing how this works. Consider the bi-gram case. If I do:

```
    In [1]: import re
    In [2]: re.findall(u'(?u)\b\w\w+\b',u'this is a sentence! this is another one.')
    Out[2]: []
```

I do not find any bigrams. Whereas:

```
    In [2]: re.findall(u'(?u)\w+ \w*',u'this is a sentence! this is another one.')
    Out[2]: [u'this is', u'a sentence', u'this is', u'another one']
```

finds some (but not all, e.g. `u'is a'` and all other even count bigrams are missing). What am I doing wrong in interpreting the `\b` character function?

Note: 
According to the regular expression module documentation, the `\b` character in [re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) is supposed to:

> \b Matches the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a word. A word is defined as a sequence of alphanumeric or underscore characters, so the end of a word is indicated by whitespace or a non-alphanumeric, non-underscore character.

I see questions addressing the issue of identifying n-grams in python (see [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17531684/n-grams-in-python-four-five-six-grams),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591258/fast-n-gram-calculation)), so a secondary question is: should I do this and add joined n-grams before feeding my text to TfidfVectorizer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should prepend regular expressions with `r`. The following works:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?u)\b\w\w+\b',u'this is a sentence! this is another one.')
[u'this', u'is', u'sentence', u'this', u'is', u'another', u'one']
```

This is a [known bug in the documentation](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/794), but if you look at the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/bb592f3865f02f1d6bf9dedce1a2554fa0ada800/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py#L414) they do use raw literals.